# Cannot find keymap 'Windows Proper Redo"

Tags: python, plugins, pycharm, intellij-plugin

A message is appearing in pycharm

Missing Keymap
Cannot find keymap 'Windows Proper Redo"

I don't know what this message means and how to solve it. Please help

Comment: Try Navigating to `settings > keymap` and select a different `keymap` from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Also, you may try to temporarily remove "PyCharm\keymaps\Default for Windows Proper Redo.xml" file and see if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You should open `Windows Proper Redo.xml` file that is located at `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\YOUR_PYCHARM_VERSION\keymaps\`, for example, at `c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.3\keymaps\` and then replace its content with the following code:

```
<keymap version="1" name="Windows Proper Redo" parent="$default">
  <action id="$Redo">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift ctrl z" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift alt back_space" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl y" />
  </action>
  <action id="EditorDeleteLine" />
</keymap>
```

Comment: This file is relocated now. For me, I found this file in:
`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\keymaps`

Comment: @PurushottamDike, the question was about PyCharm, not Android Studio, so the path hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed in my case is the following...
Goto>> C:\Users<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Google<your_android_version>\keymaps
There you will find 'Windows Proper Redo' file
Open the file in edit mode (You can use notepad like text editor)
That could most probably be empty (If not then there might be different problem) Otherwise fill as follow:

```
<keymap version="1" name="Windows Proper Redo" parent="$default">
  <action id="$Redo">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift ctrl z" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift alt back_space" />
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl y" />
  </action>
  <action id="EditorDeleteLine" />
  <action id="UpdateRunningApplication" />
  <action id="android.deploy.ApplyChanges">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl f10" />
  </action>
  <action id="android.deploy.CodeSwap">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl alt f10" />
  </action>
</keymap>
```